# logout button appearance varies from browser to browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a simple logout button using below codes :

```html
<li><a href="http://localhost:8666/web1/profile/mainpage/logout.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to logout?');">Log Out</a></li>
```

Now the logout button appearance varies between chrome and firefox :

chrome :

[image: chrome]

Firefox :

[image: ff]

**issue :** i dont want the text "localhost:8666 says" in the alert box.Also the background fades for firefox .But background doesnot fade for chrome.
How can the problem be solved for any browser?

Comment: The appearance of the dialog depends on the browser. I'm not entirely sure you can remove the *localhost:8666 says* from Chrome; it appears to be a security feature. Once your site has its own domain, it will change to that domain, for example *janewebsite.com says*.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, for security and possibly other reasons, browser dialog boxes cannot be altered. Besides, these boxes are likely system-generated, meaning HTML and CSS don't apply.

You can, however, create your own dialog / modal / pop-up boxes with JS/HTML/CSS. This will allow you to control the text and ensure a consistent appearance across browsers.

Consider these possibilities:

- http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
- http://alertifyjs.com/
- https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert